# Why does this transaction hash have multiple transactions from one address to another equal 0?

Tags: transactions, etherscan

See transactions hash:
0x88d74e7be8a951f173e4fbae1ef1bbe74cc68796 (https://etherscan.io/tx/0xc44d7eec1c7d6cb56413b2c30d6752d3b195a00833f99e39280b92d30cbb99e0)

Is there a reason why it recorded 25 transaction whose value appears to be 0 USDC/USDT? Why does stuff like this happen?

I would appreciate it if someone could explain this!!

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's a phishing attack. Basically, they're calling transferFrom() from addresses that recently transferred tokens to addresses that *looks like* the addresses they've been transferring to, hoping next time they transfer USDT, they use  the fake address by mistake. For example, address 0xe332d9fd859eee0af1497b830d64367ead8d4bfa ( https://etherscan.io/token/0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7?a=0xe332d9fd859eee0af1497b830d64367ead8d4bfa) recently transferred 143k USDT to 0x3f27abd719fdc405b83efec255222e2c68d3a9a1 and you can see in their tx history that there's a (fake) 0 USDT transfer to address 0x3f2795b71c5afadb334fcc94b053d2a7f4d1a9a1 right after that

Comment: I see, let me make sure I understand this correctly: I retrieved the previous txhash from address 0x389505f098a29a994A3ed0e674f07cd451dde42C. So X person is calling transferFrom() with the hopes of getting an accidental transfer. Why is address 0x389505f098a29a994A3ed0e674f07cd451dde42C not the one being targeted with the phishing attack? I am looking at the tx hash from earlier (https://etherscan.io/tx/0xc44d7eec1c7d6cb56413b2c30d6752d3b195a00833f99e39280b92d30cbb99e0) and neither the receiver nor the sender use address 0x389505f098a29a994A3ed0e674f07cd451dde42C. How does that work?